# Heroku cron implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, cron, ruby-on-rails-5

I am developing a webapp (deployed in Heroku) that collect live football (soccer) data and then transforms it in stats.

Currently, as I am from Uruguay, the app only collects data from the Uruguayan, Libertadores and Sudamericana competitions, that has at most, 5 matches at the same time.

The problem I am having is that I need to start a cron when each of the matches starts and end it when they end, so I can manage with more precision the current minutes of the matches.

I have been reading some posts here, but I did not found in any of them that explained how to do what I need, neither how to use it on Heroku.

If it helps, I will provide the webapp infrastrucure information:

- Ruby version: 2.4.1
- Rails version: 5.0.1
- Heroku dyno plan: Standard-2X with 1 dyno
- Heorku Postrgres plan: Hobby Basic
- Heroku stack: heroku-16

Thank you very much! And sorry for my english, clearly is not my first language.

Answer (score 0):

Personaly I like to do it like this:

- create a cron job that is executed really frequnetly, let say once per minute
- I use ruby library for scheduling that lets me set executions as I want, and they are written nicely in code, which at least in my opinion makes them more maintanable then changing cron jobs on the server. Personally I use [this library](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) (there are many to pick from).

If you are on the free tier Heroku, I'm not sure it's going to let you execute cron really frequent, but still, you can use other services that can execute code whenever you want.
For example if you are hosting your code on GitLab, it already has scheduler built in as you can use it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try this and tell you if it was succesful!